# How to do CSV lookups in ansible where the key comes from a variable?

Tags: jinja2, ansible

So ansible has the possibility of looking up things from a CSV file, the example on their web page is:

```
- debug: msg="The atomic number of Lithium is {{ lookup('csvfile', 'Li file=elements.csv delimiter=,') }}"
- debug: msg="The atomic mass of Lithium is {{ lookup('csvfile', 'Li file=elements.csv delimiter=, col=2') }}"
```

Now, my CSV file contains a mapping of hostnames to a number, like this:

```
HOST,ID
foo,0
bar,1
```

Now, when I adapt this to:

```
- debug: msg="My ID is {{ lookup('csvfile', '{{ inventory_hostname }} file=my.csv delimiter=,') }}"
```

I get the error:

```
Failed to template msg="My ID is {{ lookup('csvfile', '{{ inventory_hostname }} file=my.csv delimiter=,') }}": need more than 1 value to unpack
```

How do I do this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the string formatting

```
- debug: msg="My ID is {{ lookup('csvfile', '{} file=my.csv delimiter=,'.format(inventory_hostname)) }}"
```